# $\{(X,Y) | X \cap Y = Z \} = \{X | Z \subset X\} \times \{Y | Z \subset Y\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I want to prove question [Sum of cardinals of all intersections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777445/sum-of-cardinals-of-all-intersections-elegant-alternative-proofs) of finite set $E$.

is $\{(X,Y) |  X \cap Y = Z \} = \{X | Z \subset X\} \times \{Y | Z \subset Y\}$ where $Z \subset E$ and $X, Y \in \mathscr P(E)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have that
$$
\{(X,Y) : Z = X\cap Y\}\subset \{(X,Y) : Z\subset X\cap Y\} = \{X : Z\subset X\}\times\{Y : Z\subset Y\}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

No. The set on the right is much bigger in general.

Comment: An example illustrating your point would be helpful.

Comment: @hardmath The OP didn't make any effort to check his or her statement - $E$ a set with one element already gives a counterexample - so I don't see why I should make any effort in providing more than a minimal answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, $\{1\} \subseteq \{1,2\}$ and $\{1\} \subseteq \{1,2,3\}$, but $\{1,2\}\cap\{1,2,3\} = \{1,2\} \ne \{1\}$.